# How to Add user in Active directory using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell and trying to add user in active directory using powershell, but for some reason I cannot tab complete on New-Ad for active directory, I have tried on windows 7 client with admin right also on DC itself. Can some one please help also what would be the code to do that?

Comment: Did you run `import-module ActiveDirectory` yet?

Comment: i did that as well but there is no active directory module. I am running v 2.0 of powershell

Comment: its a live DC. so not allowed at the moment to upgrade to v3.0 , WOULD just like to know how to accomplish this

Comment: What version of server are you running?

Comment: windows server 2008 R2

Comment: Sorry, re-writing this comment. You need to install the RSAT (Remote Server Administration Tools) feature for 2008 R2. [See this link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378937(WS.10).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Apologies non of the code is formatted nicely and only has terse comments. I hope it helps though.

The code below assumes you're on a non-DC server. Not sure if this will work on a client machine, like Windows 7.

Import the server manager module and add in remote AD features...

```
# import the server manager
Import-Module ServerManager

#add in remote AD features
Add-WindowsFeature RSAT-AD-powerShell,RSAT-AD-AdminCenter

#list PS providers (one of which should be ActiveDirectory)
Get-PSProvider
```

...this should give you intellisense, assuming you're on a version of PowerShell that has intellisense.

To create a new user...

```
#create a new user
New-ADUser –Name "John Smith" –SamAccountName "john.smith" –Description "Sales Manager" –Department "Sales" –EmployeeID "45896" –Path "ou=users,ou=sales,dc=test,dc=local" –Enabled $true
```

Some other code that I scribbled down electronically, when I needed to create and explore AD users.

```
#set location to AD
cd AD:

#list available options
dir

#explore the domain (replace DCNAME with domain)
cd 'DC=DCNAME,DC=local'

#back up
cd ..

#explore users (replace DCNAME with domain)
cd 'CN=Users,DC=DCNAME,DC=local'

#look at a user
Get-ItemProperty -Path "CN=Test ADUser1"

#find specific user
Get-ADUser "TestADUser10"

#find wildcard
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(SamAccountName=*Test*)"

#get help on the aduser command
Get-Help Get-ADUser -Full
```

Comment: i was creating a test user through GUI and analysed that there are only two GUI scree, 1st screen where we specify 1st name and last name and email and next screen for password. is there a one line code that does the job just to create simple test user without putting into a special OU, or adding any further details about cities and description

Comment: Does the middle code section (New-ADUser) not accomplish this? Sorry, I can't check at the moment.